# Windows 8 wallpaper quality

Tags: windows-8, desktop-customization

So, this is pretty straightforward if you look at the image:

[image]

I have a high res 1920x1080 image. I cropped it to 1920x1080, and when I set it as wallpaper, it gets very low in quality. My display resolution is 1920x1080, so no stretching is involved.

I tried to save image as PNG and BMP and set it as background to no avail. This only happened in this specific image, others don't distort the quality so much.

What is going on? How do I change this?

Comment: if the wallpaper is smaller than the current resolution it will be zoomed to fit the screen, therefore getting blurred. try re-sizing it to your screen resolution or get the same wallpaper on the same size as your screen resolution.

Comment: thank you for your response Lorenzo Von Matterhorn but as discussed, I already scaled the image down (cropped rather) to my resolution. As can be seen from the image (http://shrani.si/f/J/vO/3WjeyO5k/capture.png), the quality of image is much higher when compared to the wallpaper (again: same resolution!)

Comment: Gone is Aero Glass, long live Aero Glass...

Comment: This is obviously an ongoing issue, far greater than some users here made it to be. Apparently, windows creates its own version of the image you want as wallpaper and while it does that, it converts it to a low quality JPEG.

Comment: Luckily, there are some people with great solutions. So, if anyone has the same issue, follow the instructions at the bottom of this link http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/why-does-windows-8-compress-your-desktop/d5470346-bd44-4349-b78f-c5480b464f91